# Ask user for TouchID/FaceID permission without actually using TouchID/FaceID

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, face-id

I'm creating an app where the user has to login and can use FaceID or TouchID to speed up the log in process.

Using FaceID or TouchID for the login can be enabled or disabled in the internal settings of the application.

When first using TouchID/FaceID the user has to grant these permissions to the app. I want that this permission request dialog appears as soon as the user enables biometric authentication in the app settings and not right before the user logs in using it.

I didn't find anything with google so I doubt this is even possible.

Comment: You have two ways to implement touchID.. `LocalAuthentication` and the raw hardcore underlying Keychain API.. LocalAuth will do fine in most situations (don't use it for Banking apps that's for sure).. Do not prompt the user for TouchID on login screen. When they enable your switch, prompt for touchID there and then store a flag in your info-plist. The next time they log-in, if the flag is present, prompt them on login.. otherwise they sign in normally.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if you prompt the user to perform Touch or Face ID when the feature is enabled within the app.

As far as I know, there is no other way to trigger this permission prompt.